# Android9, how to keep uploading position?

Tags: android, android-gps

I'm building a location uploader app and using a smartphone as a test device. But the program can't keep uploading location. Either the program or GPS will be killed (or frozen) by the phone. The following are some key points:

1. The OS is Android 9, and the phone is Nokia 6.
2. Foreground service is used and START_STICKY is returned.
3. Hold PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK.
4. Set the app to "not optimized" in "battery optimization".
5. Set the background activity to be enabled in "battery management".
6. Battery saver is off.

Even after the steps above, the upload still stops after several minutes with screen off. The progress seems to be alive, but the GPS callback does not get invoked. It resumes quickly when I unlock the phone.

So, the question is: Is there a way to build a screen-off position uploader in user mode? (The same app does not work on a rooted phone, just last longer.) It is very frustrating to fight the question.

Here is some key code:

```java
// MainService
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26)
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Log.d("MainService", "onStartCommand()");

        String channelId = "LocationUpdaterChannel";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "LocationUpdater", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Location Updater")
            .setContentText("Location updater is uploading your position.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .build();
        startForeground(5463, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

// start service
        intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainService.class);
        intent.setAction("com.jay.example.service.MAIN_SERVICE");
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) startService(intent);
        else startForegroundService(intent);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using a foreground service? A foreground service requires a notification be shown to the user and you need to call startForegroundService. See this guide for details: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Adding some code to the question would help

Comment: Of course, see item 2.

Comment: The code is straightforward, just start a foreground service and call Android location service.

Comment: I need to see how you are starting your foreground service, post some code so I can  help

Comment: It seems that I didn't call "startForegroundService". Let me change the code first.

Comment: I paste some key code. Hope helpful.

Comment: In onStartCommand change return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); to return START_STICKY; also make sure you are calling startForegroundService

Comment: OK. I'm trying it. However, it seems that the service is alive while the data (or GPS) is disrupted.

Comment: I used startService before and changed to startForegroundService (only if the sdk version >= 26). I'm testing the change and will post the result ASAP.

Comment: Code changed. The same issue remains. The data (or gps fixing) resumes after I unlock the phone.